# Function with interface as argument

Tags: java, eclipse, openlayers, vaadin

I have an interface called Layer:

```
public interface Layer {}
```

and a class that implements that interface called `VectorLayer`:

```
public class VectorLayer implements Layer {}
```

I have also a function that have `Layer` as an argument

```
public void create(Layer layer){}
```

I would like to use `create(new VectorLayer())` but eclipse throw to me the following error:

> The method create(Layer) in the type SelectFeature is not applicable
>   for the arguments (VectorLayer) 
>   VolexampleApplication.java /volExample/src/com/example/volexample

I think that normally it should work. So what is the problem here ?

**PS:**
`VectorLayer`, `Layer` and `SelectFeature.create()` are function and class from an openlayers wrapper (a library) for VAADIN.

Comment: Why are there brackets in names of classes like `interface Layer()` and `class VectorLayer()`?

Comment: @bellum Sorry typing error. I have just woke up :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you give should work fine.

Are you sure the `Layer` implemented by `VectorLayer` is the same as the one required by `SelectFeature`. You can verify this by checking the imports in both classes (or giving the fully qualified name, that is with the package name).

Comment: I have already found the solution before reading your comment. Yes you answer is correct. I discovered that I have 2 Layers each one is in a different package.

Answer (score 1):

I would try helping the compiler:

```
final Layer layer = new VectorLayer();
SelectFeature.create(layer);
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. however thanks to this try, I discovered that it is not the same Layer.
I have 2 Layer and each Layer is in a different package.